# google analytics page inside iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, google-analytics

I created a html page (iframe-content.html) which is located on www.thisdomain.com which will be loaded inside an iframe placed on another domain www.notmydomain.com.

I am using the google url builder to track the ad campaign. I also have the google analytics script added in the head of iframe-content.html so the impressions of iframe-content.html will be tracked.

What I don't want is that the tracking of iframe-content.html will be added to the tracking of www.thisdomain.com so it won't be falsified. How is this possible?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Use a different property id for the frame. The tracking code from the frame cannot access the page that hosts the frame, so there will be no interference.

Comment: Sry, it seems I was unclear with my question. My worry is that the impression-count of www.thisdomain.com which hosts the iframe-content.html will be falsified when www.notmydomain gets called.

Comment: Doesn't matter. Frames and the page the frame is displayed in are by default independent from each other, and unless you purposefully track to the same property id counts will not be inflated.

Comment: ok, thanks a lot for the clarification. I wasn't sure if google would also track pageviews of pages when they are loaded in an iframe.